# What is the pro-guard rule for StringDef annotation in android?

Tags: android, android-proguard

```
public class AssetsHelper {

    @StringDef({ScreenDensity.XHDPI,ScreenDensity.HDPI, ScreenDensity.XXHDPI})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface ScreenDensity {
        String HDPI = "HDPI";
        String XHDPI = "XHDPI";
        String XXHDPI = "XXHDPI";
    }
}
```

When I am using default pro-guard rule in tools folder of Android SDK, I am getting error for `ScreenDensity`. What is the pro-guard rule to keep this `StringDef` `ScreenDensity` from getting obfuscated?

Comment: First you should read about `RetentionPolicy.SOURCE` and then worry about proguard

Comment: @BartekLipinski - I tried RetentionPolicy.CLASS but getting same error. Any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: Can you actually post the error you're getting?

Comment: **AssetsHelper.ScreenDensity cannot be resolved to a type.**

Comment: above is the error I am getting.

Comment: ok and the referenced code?

Comment: @AssetsHelper.ScreenDensity String density = AssetsHelper.ScreenDensity.HDPI;

Comment: you said you tried `RetentionPolicy.CLASS`, have you tried `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`?

Comment: I am getting same error for RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this proguard rule:

```
-keepclassmembers class ** {
  @your.package.AssetsHelper.ScreenDensity public *;
}
```

Comment: This is what worked for me `-keepclassmembers class ** {
  @com.citruspay.graphics.AssetsHelper.ScreenDensity public *;
}`

Comment: I have also added @Keep annotation for class as well as field. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

`StringDef` is Source retention policy annotation. Therefore it will be automatically stripped off in compiled code.

Source annotations are for enforcing rules on promgrammers to use specific contants instead of "magic" numbers or strings, that mean nothing for someone unfamiliar with the code.

Comment: My code works fine in debug mode when no pro-guard rule is applied. So I guess it should work in release mode too.